# What's the best way to show a user that a field is tappable?

Tags: forms, android, toast

I have an Android application that displays information row by row. Like below

---

*Field*                         *Value*

---

*Field*                         *Value*

---

*Field*                         *Value*

---

Some of the rows can be tapped to display more information in the form of an Android Toast. I was wondering what the best way to inform the user that some of the rows are tappable. My first thought was to display an exclamation mark on the row, but it doesn't necessarily make sense for an exclamation mark to be there.

Thoughts?

Thanks for all the help, it's appreciated

Comment: Check the answers on this question: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/17438/problem-with-avoiding-right-caret-on-android?rq=1. It may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Try testing the smallest effective difference with your users.

If some of the rows are offering details on touch, you can test with your users if a link color works. Since the whole row is tappable, You could try making each value per row as a link.

[image]

You could try a background color if need be as well. This might run the risk of being confused with a selected item, so try one visual distinction first, and add another as needed.

Text can be unambiguous, and tell the user exactly which rows offer more information.

[image]

Comment: The "link color and background" isn't appropriate for Android: highlighted list items indicate multi-selection; text is not a link, this is not a webpage.

Answer (score 2):

If you are opening a new screen when tapped on rows, you could show arrow icon towards right side of the row.

[image]

Comment: Wrong, that is an iOS convention and should not be used on Android (as per Android Guidelines). You may also note the Question is tagged with `Android` and that Toasts do not exist in Android.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Will keep this in mind in future.

Answer (score 0):

Displaying more information in a Toast is not a great way to display more information. I suggest an indefinite Snackbar or some inline view (perhaps dismissable).

Don't use arrows, that is an iOS convention and frowned upon in Android. Don't be part of the problem.

If this is a list of things, lists are assumed to be clickable in Android. If you and your users really don't understand that, perhaps the app needs more hints (use meaningful text, use a tutorial/educational mechanism, or simply add a button).